# How to set a product to only ship one method

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

My website sells some products that can not go regular shipping and instead I want to use table rates for those specific items. I have looked under shipping methods and have found that it says " show if not applicable" how do you make it applicable?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to write a Plugin on

```
Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
```

and then write a before Plugin on the public function collectRates .

In this collect you can then check if the current cart items are allowed to use this method.

After this you can also write a Plugin on

```
Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
```

and also add the logic you need.